# Effectively return a JSONObject from a class to be used

Tags: java, android, json

I'm struggling to use JSON objects from one class in another.. I currently have:

```
public String URL;
public JSONObject ResultArray;

public StackTraceElement[] Error;


public void ExecJSONRequest(){


    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(this.URL);

    try {
        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        // Look for Errors
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        this.Error = e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.Error = e.getStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Get Results from URL & Populate for return
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        this.ResultArray = json;

        // Look for Errors
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        this.Error = e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my JSON Execution class (basic I know),

I'm attempting to use `ResultArray` in my main activity as:

```
    TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
    JSONQuery JSONQ = new JSONQuery();
    JSONQ.URL = "192.168.0.12/Testing/index.php";
    JSONQ.ExecJSONRequest();
    JSONObject Obj = JSONQ.ResultArray;
    url.setText(Obj.getString("url"));
```

Android studio is reporting an unhandled JSON exception.

Using a try/catch block:

```
 try {
        JSONQuery JSONQ = new JSONQuery();
        JSONQ.URL = "192.168.0.12/Testing/index.php";
        JSONQ.ExecJSONRequest();
        JSONObject Obj = JSONQ.ResultArray;
        url.setText(Obj.getString("url"));
    }catch(Exception E){
        E.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Removes this error, though my field is not populated?

---

Update. Using:

```
        // Get Results from URL & Populate for return
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        //this.ResultArray = json;
        json.getString("url");
```

inside my JSONQuery class returns the expected result (when assigning to a text field)

Comment: any logcat? try to log error message while you catch exception

Comment: @calvinfly Nothing noticeable. Will run it again and keep a closer eye on it

Comment: @calvinfly References a few breaches of the StrictMode violation policy which the line referenced is: `response = myClient.execute(myConnection);` other than that, there is no actual sign on why i'm getting an empty response, as using something similar on the JSONQuery class returns no error, will update question with what the original is

Comment: @calvinfly Figured out the complication. I was not telling the application to search HTTP. I was missing `http://` out of my assignment of `JSONQ.URL = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to try & catch this line of code

```
url.setText(Obj.getString("url"));
```

because `org.json.JSONObject#getString` will throw `JSONException` if no mapping String for the "url" key.

Alternatively, you can use `org.json.JSONObject#optString(java.lang.String)` instead. It does not throw `JSONException` and returns the empty string if no such mapping exists.